# Pytorch models deployment to sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, inference, yolov5

I have trained my yolov5 model, and have weights.pt, now I need to deploy it using sagemaker, for that I need to create an endpoint.
I'm following this tutoriel https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frameworks/pytorch/get_started_mnist_deploy.html
Since I'm working using images I'm trying to customise input_fn,output_fn functions but unfortunately when I run inference I always get errors, my question is what logic should I follow in order to customise these functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Each of these functions have a different purpose. Using the input_fn you want to prepare your input for what your model is expecting. Using the model_fn you want to load up your pytorch model. Using the predict_fn you want to have your predict/inference function code. Using output_fn you can shape the output that you return from your endpoint. Check out this article for an understanding of each of these handlers more in depth as well as examples: https://aws.plainenglish.io/adding-custom-inference-scripts-to-amazon-sagemaker-2208c3332510